# Porque não existe uma tag para Umbraco?

Tags: suporte, tags

Qual o motivo para não existir uma tag para Umbraco?
Notei que já existe uma tag para outro cms, o WordPress, então não vejo motivos para não existir a tag do Umbraco já que também é um CMS mesmo não sendo tão popular.
E já que não existe a tag, o que faço quando for postar uma pergunta relacionada a esse CMS esquecido pelo stack?

Comment: A tag é criada assim que você cria uma pergunta com a tag, alias, **se** você tiver reputação suficiente para criar a tag :) Em suma, a tag não existe, porque ninguém nunca fez uma pergunta sobre a tecnologia referida.

Comment: obrigado por esclarecer @MarceloBoni

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Caso não tenha o privilégio (são necessários 300 pontos) de criar tags, pode deixar um comentário na pergunta solicitando sua criação para outro membro que tenha esse privilégio.

Se essa tag não foi criada até agora significa que nenhuma pergunta sobre esse assunto (CMS) foi feita.

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Central de ajuda > Privilégios > criar tags](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

Comment: entendi, obrigado por esclarecer @rray

Answer (score 10):

Porque deveria existir a *tag* se ninguém fez uma pergunta sobre este assunto?

Você já tem reputação para criar *tags*, se fizer uma pergunta, coloque a *tag*.

Comment: entendi, fiquei com receio de criar e não ser adequada, muito obrigado por esclarecer @bigown

Comment: E isso só se a tag for essencial para a postagem, e estiver no escopo.